# Foreman can't use environment variables while loading rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, environment-variables, foreman

I am using RVM with Foreman with Rails 3.2. I have an .env file in my app root directory, which was supposed to be loaded with Foreman. But apparently it couldn't load rails when I use `ENV['DATABASE_NAME']` in `database.yml`. But strangely, after rails is loaded using hardcoded database name, I could open up console and access the `ENV['DATABASE_NAME']`. And Foreman really can't access `ENV` in its `Procfile` either. I have another rails 4 app that could access `ENV` in devise.rb, which is one of the initializer, but when I put the same `ENV['DATABASE_NAME']` in `database.yml`, it will start the server ok, but not able to open a page when the app is trying to access the database. So it looks like the ENV is only loaded by rails, after rails itself is loaded. How do you allow it also be accessible by `Procfile` and `database.yml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you show examples of your Profile and .env it would be be easier for someone to help out.

My wild guess from your question is you are using the env variables incorrectly in the Procfile.

If for example in .env you have
PORT=3000

then in your Profile it's referred to as $PORT -- not as ENV['PORT']

In a ruby file such as a config initializer you WOULD use ENV['FOO']

Comment: Your guess was right sir! I was using it wrong in Procfile. And following your line of thought, I was also using it wrong in the database.yml file, now I'm using `<% ENV['DATABASE_NAME'] %>` in database.yml, and it works! Thanks.

Comment: happy to help, I've certainly gotten plenty of help here on SO as well.